# Parent reference in automapped component in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

In Fluent NHibernate, given an automapped component, is there a convention for setting up a parent reference back to the "holder" of the component?

By having for example a property named Parent or something like that? I can't seem to find any information about how to do it or issues about it.

Comment: Ive have the same problem. Anyone got some feedback for this?